# autocomplete specify more parameters?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

**I'm using jquery UI autocomplete**

If I do this in jquery / asp.net:

```
 $("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").livequery(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete('LoadNames.ashx')
             .result(function (event, data, formatted) { // data[0] : Name, data[1] :AddressID
                 // Set Selected email ID to hidden field
                 $("#<%= hdnID.ClientID %>").val(data[1]);
                 if (data[1] != "0") {
                     var url = "http://emps/NewEntry.aspx?ID=" + data[1];
                     window.open(url);
                 }
                 else {
                 }
             });
            });
```

This works great, but I want to add more parameters like minChars, etc. so I try this:

```
$("#<%= txtName.ClientID %>").livequery(function () {
                $(this).autocomplete({source:"LoadNames.ashx", delay:100, minChars:2})
             .result(function (event, data, formatted) { // data[0] : Name, data[1] :AddressID
                 // Set Selected email ID to hidden field
                 $("#<%= hdnID.ClientID %>").val(data[1]);
                 if (data[1] != "0") {
                     var url = "http://emps/NewEntry.aspx?ID=" + data[1];
                     window.open(url);
                 }
                 else {
                 }
             });
            });
```

This then doesnt work any longer.  How can I add more parameters like minChars, delay, etc to this?

From the comments someone wanted to see the .ashx file, this is it but there is no issue with this.  Its just I want to add additional parameters to autocomplete:

```
 public class LoadNames : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            DataSet ds = null;
            Dictionary<long, string> lstAddresses = new Dictionary<long, string>();

            ds = GetLoginNames();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    lstAddresses.Add(Convert.ToInt64(dr["LoginID"].ToString()), dr["Login"].ToString());
                }
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (KeyValuePair<long, string> item in lstAddresses)
                {
                    builder.Append(string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}",
                          item.Value,
                          item.Key,
                          Environment.NewLine));
                }
                context.Response.Write(builder.ToString());
            }
        }

        public DataSet GetLoginNames()
        {
            SqlCommand cmdSelect = default(SqlCommand);
            SqlConnection conMyData = default(SqlConnection);
            SqlDataAdapter daIssues = default(SqlDataAdapter);
            System.Data.DataSet ds = null;

            conMyData = null;

            //try and make a connection   
            try
            {
                conMyData = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]);
                cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("selFullNames", conMyData);

                var _with1 = cmdSelect;
                _with1.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //add parameters
                _with1.Parameters.Add("@Inactive", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2;
                daIssues = new SqlDataAdapter();
                daIssues.SelectCommand = cmdSelect;
                ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
                daIssues.Fill(ds);

                return ds;
                //catch any exceptions that might be thrown
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
                //clean up and close resources
            }
            finally
            {
                conMyData.Close();
                cmdSelect = null;
                conMyData = null;
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: jQuery UI autocomplete or some other plugin?

Comment: Yes jquery ui autocomplete.

Comment: I think you can use built in `.on(` instead of `livequery` plugin - assumption of newer version of jQuery.

Comment: `LoadNames.ashx` returns what?

Comment: else {
     }, minLength:2 // Try this

Comment: @user1848739 that wont work Mark Schultheiss its a hanler that I can post but there is no issue with that...

Comment: Making `minChars:2` be `minLength:2` does not resolve it? http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength

Comment: Where to place it that is my issue?

Comment: ` $(this).autocomplete({source:"LoadNames.ashx", delay:100, minChars:2})` - `minChars:2` is not a valid option, use `minLength:2`

Comment: If I do this: `$(this).autocomplete({"LoadNames.ashx", delay:100, minLength:1})` I get an unexpected identifier js error.

Comment: you forgot the `source:` in there

Comment: Does anyone know how to specify the `options` for this?  I can type in `$(this).autocomplete("LoadNames.ashx", )` and intellisense says I can now enter `options` after the `,` so how do I do that?  That is all I am looking for.  I would need to add 2 options for instance: delay and minLength.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I dont think you are reading my code...my source is `LoadNames.ashx`.

Comment: When I say `autocomplete(` intellisense gives me 2 parameters `urlOrData` and `options` so my `urlOrData` is `LoadNames.ashx` now all I want to do is add options.

Comment: $(this).autocomplete({source:"LoadNames.ashx", delay:100, minChars:2}) Try the last bracket }) at the end of your code and combine all of them into AUTOCOMPLETE Function. Give it try

Comment: Nevermind i got it: `$(this).autocomplete("LoadNames.ashx", { minChars: 1, delay:100 })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

`$(this).autocomplete("LoadNames.ashx", { minChars: 1, delay:100 })`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("keydown.autocomplete", "#<%= txtName.ClientID %>", function (e) {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "LoadNames.ashx",
        delay: 100,
        minLength: 2
    }).result(function (event, data, formatted) {
        $("#<%= hdnID.ClientID %>").val(data[1]);
        if (data[1] != "0") {
            var url = "http://emps/NewEntry.aspx?ID=" + data[1];
            window.open(url);
        } else {}
    });
});
```